# Executing more with "exec()" function corrupts line breaking in bash

Tags: c, linux, bash

I had an exercise to write a program that will do the following pipe processing:

```
ls -la | grep "^d" | more
```

After executing my program however, the bash interpreter would not break line nor display commands correctly, however after executing them the result is showed, it looks like the input for the console is not getting on stdout but somewhere else and i cant find the reason of this behavior.

I am using 3 child process with stdio redirected to connect the pipe between them.

The program finishes successfully it shows the good result, no errors are showed or whatever, also when i am using the cat instead of more everything works normally after execution, is it possible that more changes some system values and does not change them back?

Comment: How do you execute your program? What's the code?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `more` is turning off echo and canonical mode on your TTY (see `man 3 termios`), and never switching them back on before it exits (either because it gets killed without a chance to, or because it doesn't think it's attached to a TTY). You can attach to `more` with gdb to find out why that's ahppening, or you could simply reset the terminal yourself before exiting.

Comment: hmm but I am waiting for my forked processes to finish, so its rather turning it off and does not turn it on again, i will check it later, but your explanation can be a good place to start thank you

Comment: This seems to be the bash version dependant as in the other machine the code for execing more works just fine, i will try to debug it on the machine with problems.